# Accessing objects from other classes in ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

Please forgive the newb question.  I am very new to .NET so don't assume I've done something basic.

In ASP.NET I have a form that has a Textbox named txtOutput and a button.  In the main file.aspx.vb I can call a function from the button handler and in that function I can have

```
txtOutput.Text = "Some Message"
```

with no problem.  I have a bunch of functions in several other classes.  For instance I have a class named AbleCommerce that does some database functions.  These functions are called from my main class.  In those functions, however, I have no visibility of txtOutput.  All of my classes are, unfortunately, in the default namespace which I understand is not optimal but didn't seem to impact this issue.

I know this is an easy one I've just not understood properly but it has me stumped.  My gut says that I probably need to pass the Textbox object to my "other class" but can't for the life of me figure how.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way is something like this:

```
MyTextBox.Text = MyDBClass.GetName(userID)
```

That is, you have classes that don't know about the UI, and a codebehind that takes values from the classes and assigns them to UI widgets.

Comment: Thanks, I should be able to get there now.  This is all so foreign to my linear old-school C days.  But it's fun!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing ASP.NET server controls to your DAL classes pass only the values they need like for example the text that has been entered in a textbox:

```
Dim username As String = edtUser.Text
Dim c As New AbleCommerce()
c.SomeFunction(username)
```